Select2 unslected options
I am using select2 with pagination to load more data from db when user scroll the drop down, the issue i am facing is when i select all the records and then i unselect some record then some of them show in dropdown and some not.
$(field).select2({
      allowClear: true,
      placeholder: 'Select Records',
      width: 'resolve',
      closeOnSelect: false,
      ajax: {
        url: `/programs/${field.dataset.programId}/fetch_records`,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
        },
        data: function (params) {
          $(document).on('manual-append-end', function(event) {
            return;
          });

          var query = {
            term: params.term,
            page:  params.page || 1
          }

          return query;
        },
        processResults: function (data, params) {
          debugger
          params.page = params.page || 1;
          var dropdown = $('#select2-manual_scheduler_record_ids-results')
          var existingOptions = dropdown.find('li[aria-selected="false"]').toArray();
          var existingResults = existingOptions.map(function(option) {
            return {
              id: $(option).val(),
              text: $(option).text()
            };
          });
          var combinedResults = existingResults.concat(data.results);
          return {
            results: combinedResults,
            pagination: {
              more: dropdown.find('li[aria-selected="false"]').length < 1 ? data.pagination.more : false
            }
          };
        },
        cache: true
      },
      minimumInputLength: 0
    })


  $('.select2').on('select2:unselect', function(e) {
    debugger
    var optionElement = new Option(e.params.data.text, e.params.data.id, false, false);

    $(e.target).append(optionElement).trigger('change');

    // Trigger a custom event to signal that the manual append is complete
    $(e.target).trigger('manual-append-end');
  });


 $('.select2').on('select2:unselect', function(e) {
    var unselectedValue = e.params.data.id;

    var programId = $(this).data('program-id');
    $.ajax({
      url: `/programs/${programId}/fetch_records`,
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: { term: unselectedValue, bulk: true },
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
      },
      success: function(response) {
        var newOption = response.results.find(option => option.id == unselectedValue);
        if (newOption) {
          var optionElement = new Option(newOption.text, newOption.id, false, false);
          $(e.target).append(optionElement).trigger('change');
        }
      }
    });
  });

I have tried all this but nothing is working. It would be very helpfull if some give some solution, the above solutions i tried work but after that when i open the select box the created option disappear du to the execution of data part
This is my solution that working fine for me
initializeRecordKeySelect2: function(field) {
$(field).select2({
allowClear: true,
placeholder: 'Select Records',
width: 'resolve',
closeOnSelect: false,
ajax: {
url: /programs/${field.dataset.programId}/fetch_records,
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
beforeSend: function(xhr) {
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
},
data: function (params) {
var query = {
term: params.term,
page:  params.page
}
      return query;
    },
    processResults: function(data, params) {
      params.page = params.page || 1;
      params['_type'] = 'query'

      var existingData = $(field).find('option').map(function() {
        return {
          id: $(this).val(),
          text: $(this).text()
        };
      }).get();

      var filteredData = data.results.filter(function(newItem) {
        return !existingData.some(function(existingItem) {
          return existingItem.id == newItem.id;
        });
      });

      var dropdown = $('#select2-manual_scheduler_record_ids-results')
      var nonSelectedOptions = dropdown.find('li[aria-selected="false"]').toArray()

      if (nonSelectedOptions.length > 0){
        existingData.filter(function(existingItem) {

          nonSelectedOptions.some(function(newItem) {
            if (newItem.textContent.trim() === existingItem.text.trim()) {
              $(newItem).remove();
            };
          });
        });
      }

      var combinedData = existingData.concat(filteredData);

      return {
        results: combinedData,
        pagination: {
          more: data.pagination.more
        }
      };
    }
  },
})

},
